# ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, angular6, karma-runner

I have an angular 6 application and I'm using karma + jasmine to run my tests. but when I run `ng test` I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'.

Any one knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't realized that in my `tsconfig.spec.json` I was using `jest` instead of `jasmin` in `types` node. Also, I had a missing configuration.

So, I have changed from this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.es5.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.es5.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And this changes solves my problem.

Comment: Adding "node" to my "types" array in tsconfig.json worked for me - not sure why - but it worked! thanks.

Comment: @simbro how did you even came up with that ? why node ?

Comment: I just had to add the specs and d types to my include path.

Answer (score 22):

As of Aug 2023, if you are using the latest version of `@testing-library/jest-dom`, all you need to do is remove `@types/testing-library_jest-dom`.

Comment: Live saver comment.

Comment: Not helping for me. Still the same error.

Comment: Please run npm i or pnpm i or yarn install to re-install the packages and remove the packages that are removed from package.json. Or try deleting node_modules directory and package-lock file and install all packages again

Comment: Is there a certain version of jest-dom that made the import @types/testing-library_jest-dom obsolete?